# tracking folder visited by user on osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks

***I want to make a simple cocoa application to keep track of all folder visited by me.***
I searched related document , but i am not able to find a single clue.

1. **What is the first step to achieve it?**
2. where should i **start**?
3. Is there any **notification** generated when user click on folder?
4. **Is there any history maintained by operating system which i should read?**.

Comment: "Is there any history maintained by operating system which i should read". Wow. For my privacy's sake, I sure hope not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use the FSEvents API. 
Your app will not be sandbox capable.